# How to hide file directory in AmCharts exported PDF file?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

[image]

I need to hide file directory in PDF export

Comment: How are you creating this PDF?

Comment: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/cf1cfdb933bf36a83db69a4f8ba0ebb3?editors=0010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `pageOrigin` to `false`. Please see more in the [settings documentation](https://github.com/amcharts/export#complete-list-of-available-export-settings).

```
"export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "pageOrigin": false
}
```

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/1e7c254d1ac12f644465c7b22614a81f?editors=0010

Comment: Thanks you are awsome :D

Comment: i can hide file directory in print amchart